# Combinations of two lists where same element can't be in matching position

Tags: prolog

Given the plays of several games of Rock, Paper, Scissors (out of order) and the fact that there were no draws, I would like to find the possible orderings(s). (A puzzle via [Hubert Phillips](https://www.popularmechanics.com/science/math/a27293/riddle-of-the-week-rock-paper-scissors/).)

So I have two lists that look like `[Rock, Rock, Scissors...]`.

Here is a way to find one solution in Python:

```
one, two = 'rrrssssssp', 'rrsssspppp'

while True in [t[0] == t[1] for t in zip(one, two)]:
    one = one[1:] + one[0]

print(one, two)
```

(And by iterating over that method for longer, it appears that there is only one possible solution.)

It seems like there should be a more elegant way to solve this in Prolog. Something like this?

```
% results.pl
one([r, r, r, s, s, s, s, s, s, p]).
two([r, r, s, s, s, s, p, p, p, p]).

ordered_results(L) :-
        findall((I,J), (member(I, one), member(J, one), I \== J), []).

?- [results].
?- ordered_results(one, two).
```

But this just returns True

Comment: You many problems in your current program. To get the lists, inside `ordered_results`, you need to do something like `one(One), two(Two)` and then `member(I, One)`. You also must fix the findall call to: `findall(I-J, ( member(I, One), member(J, Two), I \== J ), Result).` This still doesn't work because you will not find a list of length 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Will Ness's solution mofified to just consider rotations as it is done in the Python version (that is guaranteed to work as long as the values in `one/1` and `two/1` are sorted).

```
one([r, r, r, s, s, s, s, s, s, p]).
two([r, r, s, s, s, s, p, p, p, p]).

rotation(X, Y) :-
    append(A, B, X),
    append(B, A, Y).

one_two_ordered(X,Y):-
  one(X),
  two(B),
  rotation(B,Y),
  maplist(\=,X,Y).
```

Comment: ah yeah, this was what I was looking for. I phrased the question badly - it's not about permutations but more like sorting

Answer (score 4):

We only need to reorder one of them:

```
one_two_ordered(X,Y):-
  one(X),
  two(B),
  permutation(B,Y),
  maplist(\=,X,Y).
```

This produces lots and lots of answers.

If you want efficiency, you need to fuse the two last goals together. Or we can try using `dif/2` and switch the order of execution, to have the  `permutation`'s choices *guided* by the constraints in place:

```
one_two_(X,Y):-
  one(X),
  maplist(dif,X,Y),
  two(B),
  permutation(B,Y).
```

This now finds the first solution after just *689* inferences, in SWI Prolog, instead of the ***7,677,050*** inferences of the first version.

Comment: This is not really helping solve the problem in any significant way? You would want the solution to be found relatively quickly...

Comment: they asked for an _elegant_ way. this is declarative and elegant, a starting point, to be improved if searching _then_ for efficiency.

Comment: @TA_intern I've edited with a much more efficient, and still declarative, solution. :)

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for :-)

Comment: yeah thanks for the push. it's actually nice to see both solutions side by side I think. :)

Comment: Note that the Python version takes advantage of the fact that you don't need to try all the permutations but only rotations. Same thing could be done in Prolog.

Comment: @salva I haven't gleaned that from the question, that the two lists are supposed to be sorted. I haven't understood much in it after the opening sentence (and the title). now it makes more sense, thanks (except for the Prolog code which is still a mystery). it's all very cryptic and underhanded. a "method" which isn't, is "iterated" (what does that mean unless you know what it means?) but from the middle... the key assumption is omitted... (perhaps it's in the link?) half-implements rotations without mentioning the word rotation in the text...

Comment: (and it even says "out of order"...)

Comment: @WillNess yes, yes, that's true... I just get that from the Python code, though if you follow the link to the riddle, you will see that what you get as inputs are actually the counts of `r`, `s` and `p`.

Comment: Also, it is far from obvious that it happens that if a solution exists, then a solution that is a rotation (after sorting the input vectors) must also exist!

Answer (score 3):

It's not intuitive that this riddle has a proper solution, then I coded a solver, beyond your question:

```
/*  File:    rock_paper_scissor.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Sep 20 2021
    Purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69246908/874024
*/

:- module(rock_paper_scissor,
          [puzzle/2]).

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

puzzle(WhoWins, ByHowMuch) :-
    count_wins("rrrssssssp", "rrsssspppp", WinAdam, WinEve),
    (   WinAdam > WinEve
    ->  WhoWins = adam, ByHowMuch is WinAdam - WinEve
    ;   WhoWins = eve , ByHowMuch is WinEve - WinAdam
    ).

win(r,s).
win(p,r).
win(s,p).

count_wins([A|As], Es, WinAdam, WinEve) :-
    select(E,Es,Er),
    E\=A,
    count_wins(As, Er, WinAdam1, WinEve1),
    (   win(A,E)
    ->  WinAdam is WinAdam1+1, WinEve is WinEve1
    ;   WinAdam is WinAdam1, WinEve is WinEve1+1
    ).
count_wins([], [], 0, 0).
```

yields

```
?- setof(W-N,puzzle(W,N),L).
L = [adam-4].
```

Exchanging Adam and Eve moves (i.e. `count_wins("rrsssspppp", "rrrssssssp", WinAdam, WinEve),`) we get `[eve-4]`. Seems it's correct then...

Comment: naming it `ensure_no_draws_and_count_wins/4` is perhaps too unwieldy... `no_draws_count_wins/4` could be a good compromise.

Comment: Thanks, I made a hash of describing the question but you have correctly solved the actual riddle and used combinations instead of rotations.

Comment: @JoshFriedlander this answer is doing what I referred to in my answer as "fusing the two last goals together", writing out "by hand" what `permutation` is doing automagically in the presence of the `dif` constraint (in the 2nd snippet in my answer) -- it also `select`s an element, an the constraint rejects any selection of the same value -- just as the code in this answer is doing explicitly (i.e. "by hand") with `E\=A`. it is the same thing exactly. (except that it also counts the wins).